# Convert AR mobile application to VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, ar-foundation

I have created an AR mobile application using unity. So the application works fine and placing the AR objects correctly.

Now I need to view this AR application through a VR Box. Like the google cardboard VR box, inserting my mobile phone with created web application and view the AR objects in virtual reality.

Is it possible? Do I need to change my Unity project type or any other method like converting the AR application to compatible with VR box?